# Python phonenumbers: how to get the required number of digits of a mobile phone in a country?

Tags: python, libphonenumber, python-phonenumber

I want to use python phonenumbers to get the number of digits that mobile phones have to have for each country.

I'm importing the phonenumbers/libphonenumber library.

I tried fetching the metadata with no success. Then I tried fetching an example number to then deduce it from there. It looks like I'm not being able to give with the adequate attributes or classes to fetch these. Do you know which are the attributes or classes I need to look for in order to get to this information?

```
country = phonenumbers.region_code_for_country_code(country_code)
metadata = phonenumbers.metadata_for_region(country)
```

or

```
region_code = phonenumbers.region_code_for_country_code(country_code)
example_number = phonenumbers.get_example_number_for_type(region_code, phonenumbers.PhoneNumberType.MOBILE)
```

I'm open to using other libraries too.

Comment: Which Python version are you using?

Comment: Hi! I'm using version 3.10.8

Answer (score -2):

You can try this code that retrieves the required number of digits of a mobile phone number in a specific country using your database:

```
import sqlite3

def get_mobile_number_digits(country_code):
    # Connect to the database
    conn = sqlite3.connect("phone_number_format.db")
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    
    # Query the database for the required number of digits for the given country code
    query = "SELECT num_digits FROM phone_number_format WHERE country_code=?"
    cursor.execute(query, (country_code,))
    result = cursor.fetchone()
    
    # Close the database connection
    cursor.close()
    conn.close()
    
    # Return the result
    if result:
        return result[0]
    else:
        return None
```

The database phone_number_format.db has a table named phone_number_format with columns country_code and num_digits. The get_mobile_number_digits function takes a country_code as input and returns the required number of digits for that country code. If the country code is not found in the database, the function returns None.

Comment: The thing is I don’t have such database. I’m trying to extract the information from the library, using it as the database.

Comment: I can ensure you that it's not a unique number for one country. It always is a range from minimum to maximum length